# What's faster ? if() function() OR function(){ if() }?

Tags: php, function, if-statement

Imagine you have one function that does stuff under one condition, eg. if an array is not empty.

Would it be faster, in the case `$array` is empty :

```
function dostuff($array){
    // stuff
}

if(!empty($array)) dostuff($array);
```

Or :

```
function dostuff($array){
    if(!empty($array)){
        // stuff
    }
}

dostuff($array);
```

I know, "you're talking about milliseconds here", but i'm just curious, and i will "write the code that makes the most sense to me" anyway ;)

Comment: "**Premature optimization is the root of all evil.**" [Quote](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth#Computer_Programming_as_an_Art_.281974.29)

Comment: @Matt: Incomplete citations are sometimes too.

Comment: I would not even ask the question... it depends on how `dostuff` is supposed to work. Based on that you have to decide for one way, no matter (independent form speed). If you want to find out which is faster, put the code in a loop, take the current time, execute the loop 10.000 times and get the time difference.

Comment: @Mario "Misquotation is, in fact, the pride and privilege of the learned. A widely- read man never quotes accurately, for the rather obvious reason that he has read too widely." ;)

Comment: @Matt And sometimes it's still nice to just satisfy curiosity.

Comment: Don't worry about it yet.  Avoid micro optimization and premature optimizations, they cost far more than you realize.  See [A blog post I wrote on the subject](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2011/08/on-optimization-in-php.html)...  write clean and working code, then and only then optimize, but only **if** necessary, and only as much as necessary.

Comment: @mario For you: "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil.
Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%. A good programmer will not be lulled into complacency by such reasoning, he will be wise to look carefully at the critical code; *but only after that code has been identified*." - Knuth, 1974 :)

Comment: @AndyPerfect Thank you for understanding, as i've written above, that it's just out of curiosity that i was asking this question :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first is faster as there is overhead when calling a function (or rather, you put the check earlier), but really, never ever think about this unless you are doing it 10.000 times in a loop... but then you should inline it instead if the function is so simple that it would actually noticeably improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how if PHP has a runtime stack, but if it does, whenever a function is called, all of the variables stored during that routine are thrown onto that stack and then retrieved once the function has terminated. If you only have to do that call when the if statement evaluates to true, then that is a teeny bit of time saved.

That said, it is such a small amount of time there is most likely no reason to worry about it. Put the if statement wherever it makes more sense to be.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use a [profiler to actually check](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler) you would find that it's hardly measurable for a single call, but avoiding the possibly redundant function call is a bit speedier.

I'd like to advise that you look onto readability here instead. If you have the option of avoiding a check (the function is autonomous), then go for that.